# Strange results when plotting (Cormen) Red-black tree insert

Tags: python, big-o, red-black-tree

I implemented in Red-Black trees in Python according to the pseudo code in Cormen's `Introduction to Algorithms`.

I wanted to see in my own eyes that my `insert` is really `O(logn)` so I plotted the time it takes to insert `n=1, 10, 20, ..., 5000` nodes into the tree.

This is the result:

[image]

the `x`-axis is `n` and the `y`-axis is the time it took in **milliseconds**.

To me the graph looks more linear than logarithmic. What can explain that?

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/559501/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the graph displays a measurement of the cost of inserting `n` elements into your tree, where the x axis is how many elements we've inserted, and the y axis is the total time.

Let's call the function that totals the time it takes to insert n elements into the tree `f(n)`.

Then we can get a rough idea of what `f` might look like:

```
f(1) < k*log(1)                 for some constant k.

f(2) < k*log(1) + k*log(2)      for some constant k

...

f(n) < k * [log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n)]   for some constant k.
```

Due to how logs work, we can collapse `log(1) + ... + log(n)`:

```
f(n) < k * [log(1*2*3*...*n)]     for some constant k

f(n) < k * log(n!)                for some constant k
```

We can take a look at Wikipedia to see a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) of what `log(n!)` looks like.  Take a look at the graph in the article.  Should look pretty familiar to you.  :)

That is, I think you've done this by accident:

```
for n in (5000, 50000, 500000):
    startTime = ...
    ## .. make a fresh tree
    ## insert n elements into the tree
    stopTime = ...
    ## record the tuple (n, stopTime - startTime) for plotting
```

and plotted total time to construct the tree of size n, rather than the individual cost of inserting one element into a tree of size n:

```
for n in range(50000):
    startTime = ...
    ## insert an element into the tree
    stopTime = ...
    ## record the tuple (n, stopTime - startTime) for plotting
```

---

Chris Taylor notes in the comments that if you plot `f(n)/n`, you'll see a log graph.  That's because a fairly tight approximation to `log(n!)` is `n*log(n)` (see the Wikipedia page).  So we can go back to our bound:

```
f(n) < k * log(n!)                for some constant k
```

and get:

```
f(n) < k * n * log(n)             for some constant k
```

And now it's should be easier to see that if you divide `f(n)` by `n`, your graph will be bounded above by the shape of a logarithm.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was about to post! Zack, if you plot `f(n)/n` then you will see your log graph appear plain as day.

Answer (score 3):

`5000` might not be large enough to really "see" the logarithm -- try runs at `50000` and `500000`. If it takes two seconds and twenty seconds, then linear growth makes sense. If it takes less, then logarithmic makes sense. If you zoom in closely enough on most "simple" functions, the results look pretty linear.

Comment: so `50000` takes 2.5 seconds and `500000` takes ~30, which does look linear according to your conjecture

Answer (score 2):

There are always a handful of speculations to any 'why' question.  I would suspect the jumps you are seeing are related to system memory management.  If the system has to allocate a larger memory space for continued growth, it would add a given amount of time to complete the processing of the whole program.  If you added a 'payload' field to you nodes, thus increasing the amount of storage space needed, and I am correct, the jumps will happen more often.

Nice graph, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, you must have seen the pre-edit version which used pypy. I believe that was the reason for the jumps.